# What are strange characters and dashed lines above switches?

Tags: switches, schematics, symbol

In the picture below, what are the weird symbols over the switches?  I've circled or pointed to them with red.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a part list or model number for s1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dashed line represents a mechanical instead of electrical connection.

On a push button like s2 s3 s4 it's a redundant symbol.

S1 is a Emergency Stop NC Turn Reset type switch. It needs to be twisted to reset if pushed. The dash line, the z bar, and the dip represent this.

The D represents the mushroom head of the switch.

The Z is the twist action. If it was a ] bracket it would be a pull to reset. [ would be pushed to reset. There is also switches with key reset, represented by a keyhole.

Unsure what the block represents.

The V notch is the latching.

And Normally Connected switch symbol is because it is closed when not pushed.

Answer (score 12):

Try these: -

[image]

There are more explanations on the site [where I took the image](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2019/09/switch-push-button-symbols.html).

- S1 is a latching rotary activated switch
- S2 is a momentary action push-button (normally open)
- S3 is same as S2
- S4 is same as S2 but normally closed